# Can't return value of fileReader result in AngularJS service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, service, controller

I'm trying to write a service which reads the image file from an HTML input element. I want this service to return the HTML img object with the updated attribute from the read image file (the base64 string). My service is now this:

```
.service('ReadLocalImageService', [function () {

    this.openLocalImage = function (file) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function (e) {
            img.src = e.target.result;
        };
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
         return img.src;
    };

}]);
```

The `img.src` in this case is returned empty, like this:

[image: Console log from img.src]

If I put a `console.log(img.src)` inside the `fileReader.onload`, it prints out what I want. It seems like the function `openLocalImage` is returning the `img.src` before `e.target.result` is assigned to it.

I couldn't manage to work this around nor find the correct topic about this problem. Could anyone help me solve this or explain me why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because img was not loaded yet. Here is a solution

```
.service('ReadLocalImageService', [function () {

    this.openLocalImage = function (file, callback) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function (e) {
            img.src = e.target.result;
            callback(img.src);
        };
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    };

}]);
```

We will pass a `callback` function and receive `img.src` as its param. To use it

```
ReadLocalImageService.openLocalImage(myImage, function(imgSrc) {
    // use imgSrc
});
```